# Trouble in downloading and installing Sitecore CMS

Tags: content-management-system, sitecore, permission-denied

I am new to CMS Tool, so trying to workout with **SiteCore CMS Tool**.
Went through many blogs but could not get clarity on where to start.Tried to download from SDN but got the following error **"Insufficient Rights..Permission Denied"**

[image: Screenshot of error I got]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYMeN.png

What does this error mean??....So
My Questions are
****1. Any License/Exams required to start with Sitecore CMS,Suggestion for Installation and Starting with Sitecore CMS?
2. Any tutorial where I can get info regarding StartUp.****

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To download a fuly licensed version of Sitecore you will need to actually buy it. Just registering for the Sitecore Developer Network (SDN) doesn't give you rights to it.

If you're just trying to learn Sitecore privately then what you need is Sitecore Express, which is for non-comercial use:

http://xpress.sitecore.net/

EDIT: You will have to contact Sitecore for a copy: http://www.sitecore.net/Company/Contact (thanks Yan Skylarenko)

There's lots of info for installing Sitecore on the SDN, as well as plenty of tutorials, cookbooks and references.
Installation guides:
http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Sitecore%20V5/Sitecore%20CMS%206/Installation.aspx

Sitecore fundamentals:
http://sdn.sitecore.net/Developer/Training%20Materials/Fundamentals.aspx

Building a basic site:
http://sdn.sitecore.net/Developer/Training%20Materials/Basic%20Site.aspx

Comment: To add to James' answer you also need to pass Sitecore training before you have access to download the software. If you are a Sitecore Partner and need access before you have been trained you can contact your regional office who can arrange access to the download section.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, didn't realise that as I had access before I'd been certified :-)

Comment: Unable to find any download link from http://xpress.sitecore.net/ .. Is it like Sitecore training is compulsory even for XPress edition??